# VBA Macro to AutoFill Right until Last Column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report that is automatically pulled that requires Sums to be added at the end of certain columns. The report remains static from Column A-R but the amount of columns as of S can be as few as 1 or go up until 52. The amount of rows are never static. I already know how to find the last row and my sums need to start at column J but when I try to autofill to the right to the last column that contains data (on the same row I have summed J), it spits back an error or doesn't work. Anyone know how to do this? This is what I have for code thus far.

```
Sub TV_Buysheet()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'



    Range("J1").Select
    FIRST_ROW = ActiveCell.Row
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    LAST_ROW = ActiveCell.Row
    Selection.Offset(2, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[" & FIRST_ROW - LAST_ROW - 2 & "]C:R[-2]C)"
Dim lastCol As Long
lastCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

 ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, lastCol), Type:=xlFillDefault

      End Sub
```

Just missing the line of code that autofills to the last column...

Comment: could you precise how you determine `FIRST_ROW` and `LAST_ROW` and what the error is ?

Comment: Sorry I missed some code: 
`Sub TV_Buysheet()
'
' Macro1 Macro

'



    Range("J1").Select

    FIRST_ROW = ActiveCell.Row

    Selection.End(xlDown).Select

    LAST_ROW = ActiveCell.Row

    Selection.Offset(2, 0).Select

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[" & FIRST_ROW - LAST_ROW - 2 & "]C:R[-2]C)"

Dim lastCol As Long

lastCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


 ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, lastCol), Type:=xlFillDefault

    
      End Sub

`
    The error is basically a global error... I know it's my autofill causing the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the last column, the following should work

```
Dim lngLastColumn As Long

lngLastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

Range(Activecell, Cells(Activecell.Row, lngLastColumn)).FillRight
```

Comment: I have no problem finding the last column via VBA it's when I want to autofill to the last column that isn't working...

Comment: I just updated my answer to show how to use the lngLastColumn variable to fill right from the activecell @RachelArts

Comment: Amazing! Worked perfectly!